# SQL Stored Procedure: Conditional Return

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, branch

Hi I want to create a simple stored proecudre which does the following:

Psudocode

```
@tempSelect = "SELECT * FROM Table"

if (@Param is NULL) then
 exec @tempSelect
else
 exec @tempSelect + ' WHERE id = ' + @Param + '
```

Is this method efficent?  Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
select *
from table
where id=isnull(@param, id)
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was a better way.

Comment: +1 Nice - easy to understand and better than my answer unless you were working with huge datasets (which I'd hope you aren't if you'll be returning everything).

Comment: With that solution you might hit a performance problem because the index on the ID column will not be used.  I don't know about your DB but i'm pretty sure it's the case with Oracle's NVL function.

Answer (score 1):

Select * from Table
Where (ID = @Param or @Param is null)

Or

Select * from Table
Where ID=Coalesce(@Param, ID)

[And if you are aiming for efficiency, replace * with the specific field you want to return.]

Answer (score 0):

Yes - I certainly see nothing wrong with it.  You could make it even simpler though:

```
Set NOCOUNT On;
if (@Param is NULL) 
   Select * From Table;
else 
   Select * From Table Where (ID=@Param);
```

Note: I'd probably spell out the fields, though.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the case, I would probably use dynamic SQL.

However you need to remember about SQL injection in case @param originates from a user, thats why you should never add a parameter directly to your sql.

In t-sql it would look something like (out of my head and untested ;):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = N'
  SELECT ...
  FROM   table t
  WHERE  1 = 1' (

IF(@param IS NOT NULL)
  SET @SQL = @SQL + '
    AND t.id = @id'

... possibly more things added to the query ...

EXEC sp_executesql 
   @SQL
, '@id AS INT'
,  @id = @Param
```

By doing this, you will get an optimized query plan for each case (and by using sp_executesql, the query cache will be used as well)

I would especially avoid the OR solution, if you check the query plans generated with the OR compared to one without, you will understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureName]
@Param varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

declare @tempSelect nvarchar(max)  

SET NOCOUNT ON;

set @tempSelect = 'SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Table where Col1 <> '' '

         if @Param <> '' 
    begin
    set @resultSet = @resultSet +  ''' and Col1='''+@Param1 
    end


EXEC(@resultSet)

END
```