# SQL Prepared Statements for complex filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok, so I know you should use prepared statements to avoid injection attacks as well as for the huge speed improvements, but there is still one place that I find myself doing string manipulation to build my sql query.

Suppose I have a search feature that consists of six or seven or n dropdown lists.  Based on whether there is a default value in each of those lists I want to append an item to my where clause.  Is there a good way to do this with prepared statements where I can pass the parameters to a stored procedure and have it determine whether or not to include each particular where clause?

Comment: Could you please give an example of a query you want to build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No question like this would be complete without a link to this article.  It goes over the use of Exec and sp_executesql, and discusses SQL Injection in depth, within the context of Dynamic SQL:

**The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL**
http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: I believe your link is broken?

Comment: I just tried it, works OK for me. Are you blocked from using .se domains?

Comment: +1 Because the answer is "it depends" and Erland took the time to show you how to figure that out.

Comment: bah, stupid local intranet use the .se tld - didn't notice that.  Google cache has me covered though.  Excellent read, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The server should optimize out queries such as `where field like '%'`, so I would just prepare a statement with everything. This would probably also make your code a lot simpler.

Comment: Unbearably simpler, I can't believe I didn't think of using like.  Wouldn't that put a big hit on performance otherwise though?  I was under the impression that like was a good bit slower than =.

Comment: Good intuition, but it's not a big deal. See: http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/jnelson/archive/2007/11/16/108354.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is parameterised SQL with sp_ExecuteSQL ... something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SampleTest
    @val1 INT
    @val2 INT
AS
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)

    SET @sql = N'SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM dbo.table WHERE 1 = 1'

    IF @val1 IS NOT NULL
       SET @sql = @sql + ' AND col3 = @pVal1'

    IF @val2 IS NOT NULL
       SET @sql = @sql + ' AND col4 = @pCol4'

    EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @sql, '@pVal1 INT, @pVal2 INT', @val1, @val2
```

SQL Server will then cache execution plans the minimum number of execution plans with maximum flexibility in your SQL. Using sp_ExecuteSQL in this way as well means that it's secure from SQL injection attacks as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659033/sql-stored-procedure-conditional-return/659040#659040) to SO question [SQL Stored Procedure: Conditional Return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659033/sql-stored-procedure-conditional-return/659040) ... I think you could use the same type of thing.